# Fixing a flutter lint for late variable

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

I have the following flutter dart code which uses the geolocator package.

```
Position? _position;
  void _getCurrentLocation() async {

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
    Position position = await _determinePosition();

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _position = position;

      lat = position.latitude.toString();
      long = position.longitude.toString();
}
```

I am getting a lint warning (see below) on _position and it is greyed out saying that "The value of the field '_position' isn't used. (Documentation)  Try removing the field, or using it."

```
Position? _position;
```

If I comment the line out I get an error under setState for _position = position saying
Undefined name '_position'.

The code works and I don't know if its best to just ignore the lint or if there is a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you have **assigned** the value, the Dart analyzer knows that you haven't **use** it. Start **using** the value somewhere else, maybe in a `Text` widget, and the warning will be gone.